# Context Api with typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-context

I am kind of new with with typescript and react combined. So here I have Context and simple Modal funcions and states, I wanna use them globally but it is not letting me pass them in the HomeContext.Provider value. Is interface good?

```
import React,{useState} from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom"
 const HomeContext = React.createContext<Props | boolean>(null);

interface Props{
  setIsModalOpenTwo: (value: boolean) => void;
  closeModalOne: (value: boolean) => void;
  closeModalTwo: (value: boolean) => void;
  setIsModalOpenOne: (value: boolean) => void;
  modalIsOpenOne: boolean;
  openModalTwo: (value: boolean) => void;
  openModalOne: (value: boolean) => void;
  modalIsOpenTwo: boolean;
}

export const HomeProvider:React.FC<Props> = ({ children } ) => {

    const [modalIsOpenOne, setIsModalOpenOne] =useState(false)
    const [modalIsOpenTwo, setIsModalOpenTwo] =useState(false)


    const  closeModalOne=()=>{
        setIsModalOpenOne(false);
      }
      const  openModalOne=()=>{
        setIsModalOpenOne(true);
      }

      const  closeModalTwo=()=>{
        setIsModalOpenTwo(false);
      }
      const  openModalTwo=()=>{
        setIsModalOpenTwo(true);
      }
  
  return (

   
    <HomeContext.Provider
      value={{ closeModalOne, openModalOne,setIsModalOpenTwo, modalIsOpenOne, modalIsOpenTwo, setIsModalOpenOne, openModalTwo, closeModalTwo}}
    >
    <>
      {children}
      </>
    </HomeContext.Provider>
  );
}

export { HomeContext,  };
```

Comment: What does it mean "not letting me pass them", what is the error?

Comment: @DennisVash ```Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'boolean | Props'```

Comment: Makes sense... Your context does not accept null, `Props|boolean`

Comment: what it should be then

Comment: If I change the boolean to a null, when I  try to use any state, it is telling that is a "state'' is not being found in the props |"null

Comment: I think you are assigning your `Props` interface to the wrong component. `HomeProvider` receives only a `children` prop, it's the `useContext` hook that should specify the `Props` interface type if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: I have to wrap the HomeContext arond App/Main Component in the index.tsx file? is that what yo are saying

Answer (score 1):

So, I needed to create a Context

```
 const HomeContext =  React.createContext<Props>({
  modalIsOpenOne: false,
  modalIsOpenTwo: false
  ...
 })
```